# Gazebo with GWSL: Opens and Closes

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux, ubuntu-20.04

Running Windows 10 (ver 21H1 19043.1415).

From the MS Store, OpenInWSL & GWSL were installed. These were tested and performed as expected.

Then also from MS Store, Ubuntu 20.04 was installed.  Ubuntu performed as expected.  User and PW were entered, then Ubuntu was updated and upgraded.

GIMP was installed in Ubuntu and ran as expected.  In GWSL, GIMP showed as a Linux App.  GIPM starts and runs as expected from the Linux App list in GWLS.  When running, GIMP opens in X server running on localhost: 0.0

Gazebo was installed per the "one liner" instructions at the following website:

http://gazebosim.org/tutorials?tut=install_ubuntu&cat=install

```
curl -sSL http://get.gazebosim.org | sh
```

The Gazebo install did NOT result in having Gazebo added to the list showing in GWSL Linux Apps.

When Gazebo is run, Gazebo's start image displays briefly in X running on localhost: 0.0.  Then Gazebo closes leaving the X running on localhost: 0.0, empty.

So some assistance would be greatly appreciated with getting Gazebo to fully start running in this environment.

[image]